# BING API 2.0 Issues versus regular search

Tags: php, api, bing, bing-api

We recently started using the Bing API after finding Goolge's search not working out for our needs.  I was able to get a demo prototype working with the api.  My interest is gathering the results from a search using the "site:domain.com" to pull pages that Bing has cached.

I'm getting descrepent results between the API call and a regular search on Bing.
First I do a search on: site:silvatechsolutions.com (in the main search engine).  That seems to work great and I get a lot of results.

The same API call does NOT return the same amount of results:
http://api.search.live.net/xml.aspx?Appid=YOURAPPKEYHERE&sources=web&Web.count=30&query=site%3Asilvatechsolutions.com

I only get 3 results total.  The weird thing is, it seems to work on a few other domains but the two that I tested (and the sites have been up for a few years without major changes) have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying a mobile app with the Bing API, having troubles to get my requests right. Thats how I got on this page.
As far as I know, Bing has changed their API:

Developers with existing AppIDs can continue using Bing Search API 2.0 until August 1, 2012. On and after this date, Bing Search API 2.0 AppIDs will no longer return results. Developers can continue using the API by signing up for it in the Windows Azure Marketplace. Read the Migration Guide and FAQs to get started.

Migration guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx
FAQ: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252146&clcid=0x409

You should now use the Azure API.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here - but the sample url you have here doesn't actually include query text... just "site:silvatechsolutions.com" in the query parameter.

As far as I know query text is required when making API calls.

Comment: But then what is it searching for and returning results?